# Get emails from SharedMailbox folder

Tags: vba

I want to get all emails from specific folder from Shared mailbox.
I know how to do that from local mailbox. I have tried to obtain emails in similar way from SharedMailbox and it worked one time. Every next time I run the macro there is error on line:

```
Set folder = folder.Folders(Sub_Folder) in "Shared mailbox" block
```

> Error: Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)': Automation error

```
Sub GetEmailsFromSharedMailboxFolder()

'Declare Variables
Dim app As Outlook.Application
Dim nameSpace As Outlook.nameSpace
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objOwner As Object
Dim item As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Sub_Folder As String
Dim Shared_Mailbox As String

'Input Variables
Sub_Folder = "Very_Important"
Shared_Mailbox = "Giants_Hunters@Fake_Company.com"


'Shared Mailbox block
    'Set owner
    Set objOwner = nameSpace.CreateRecipient(Shared_Mailbox)
    'Set default Folder
    Set folder = nameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, 6)

    'Set subfolder
    If Sub_Folder <> "" Then
        Set folder = folder.Folders(Sub_Folder)
    End If
'Shared Mailbox block

'Save emials subject
i = 1
For Each item In folder.Items
    Range("A" & i) = item.Subject
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved:
I had to Open outlook -> File -> Account Settings ->Account Settings... 
In Email tab click button "Change" and uncheck "Use Chached Exchange Mode to download email to an Outlook data file" then click "Next".